# Write usb bulk windows with winusb

Tags: qt, usb, winusb

Im trying to send some data using the bulkout endpoint of a usb device.
I can open the usb device (corsair k65rgb keyboard) interface 2 (which control the lighting) using createfile and SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail.
But the example code I have write data using HidD_SetFeature. And from the usb sniffer it write urb function classe interface (using the control endpoint)
but when I open corsair cue software it use urb function bulk or interrupt transfer.

So I know its possible to send bulk data. But im lost on how to do it 
Thank you

I use QT 5.9 and VS2015

Answer (score 0):

You could try the winusb call **WinUsb_WritePipe()** for transfering data using bulk transfers.
A interface handle is required before we can use WinUsb calls.It is obtained by using setupApi calls and after the required device is found.
Use **CreateFile()** call to open the file handle and perform **WinUsb_Initialise()** to obtain the interface handle.
We can use this interface handle for further WinUsb calls.For Bulk transfer we would also require pipe(Endpoint) information which can be obtained by 
**WinUsb_QueryPipe()** call.
Check the following reference for list of winusb calls: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/
This is an example code for Bulk transfer using a winusb call.

```
    BOOL WriteToBulkEndpoint(WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE hDeviceHandle, UCHAR* pID, ULONG* pcbWritten)
{
    if (hDeviceHandle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || !pID || !pcbWritten)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL bResult = TRUE;

    UCHAR szBuffer[] = "Hello World";
    ULONG cbSize = strlen(szBuffer);
    ULONG cbSent = 0;

    bResult = WinUsb_WritePipe(hDeviceHandle, *pID, szBuffer, cbSize, &cbSent, 0);
    if(!bResult)
    {
        goto done;
    }

    printf("Wrote to pipe %d: %s \nActual data transferred: %d.\n", *pID, szBuffer, cbSent);
    *pcbWritten = cbSent;


done:
    return bResult;

}
```

Check the following reference for more details:
Refer:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/nf-winusb-winusb_writepipe